The expected value of the sum of squared positives of $n$ i.i.d. normal random variables
Let $X_1$, $X_2$,...,$X_n$ be $n$ i.i.d. normal random variables, with $X_i$ following $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and $n$ denoting a finite number. I am asking if the expected value of the sum of the squared positive $X_i$ equals a value I derived:
$E[\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i^2\times I_{X_i>0})]=n*[1-\Phi(-\mu/\sigma)]*E(Z_i^2)$,
where $I_{X_i>0}$ is an indicator function to identify the positive $X_i$, $\Phi(.)$ is the cumulative function of the standard normal, and $Z_i$ are i.i.d. truncated normal random variables (bounding the $X_i$ random variable from above zero).
This derivation is based on my thought that if we repeat the $X_i$ in long run we have $X_i\times I_{X_i>0}$ is closing to $Z_i$ such that $E(X_i^2\times I_{X_i>0})=E(Z_i^2)$, and we obverse $Z_i$ in the window size of $n*[1-\Phi(-\mu/\sigma)]$ due to the summation of $n$ of $X_i$, $\sum_{i=1}^n$. This window is calculated by the expected frequency of positives in $X_1$, $X_2$,...,$X_n$. Therefore, we have $E[\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i^2\times I_{X_i>0})]=n*[1-\Phi(-\mu/\sigma)]*E(Z_i^2)$.

Your expression looks as if it can be justified using linearity of expectation rather than "repeat the $X_i$ in long run". There will also be an expression for $E[Z_i^2]$ if you want to use it.

First use linearity :
$$E[\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i^2 \times 1_{X_i>0})] = n E[X_1^2 \times 1_{X_1>0}] = n\mathbb{P}(X_1>0)E[Z_i^2]$$
In the case that $\mu = 0$ you have that $X_1$ is symmetrical, so that $X_1^2 \times 1_{X_1>0} \overset{(d)}{=} X_1^2 \times 1_{X_1<0}$. Thus $$E[X^2_1 \times 1_{X_1>0}] = \frac{1}{2}E[X_1^2\times 1_{X\not = 0}] = \frac{\sigma^2}{2}$$
Otherwise, you can give and integral expression :
$$E\left[X_1^2 1_{X_1 > 0}\right] = \int_0^\infty \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx$$
You have a close expression (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution) :
$$E[X^2_1 1_{X_1> 0}] = \mathbb{P}(X_1 > 0)E[X_1^2\mid X_1>0] = (\sigma^2 +\mu^2)\left(1-\Phi(\frac{-\mu}{\sigma})\right)+ \mu\sigma\varphi(\frac{-\mu}{\sigma})$$

In your first equation, do you assume that all $X_1, X_2,...,X_n$ is positive? I think there will be some negative value among $X_1, X_2,...,X_n$. Also, your first equation is based on the symmetry of $X_i$ around zero, but in my question $X_i$ is symmetrical around $\mu$.

For the first equation : you don't need to assume that the $X_i$ are positive. The linearity of expectation says that $$E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i^2 \times 1_{X_i > 0} \right] = \sum_{i=1}^n E[X_i^2\times 1_{X_i>0}] = nE[X_1^2\times 1_{X_1 > 0}].$$
For the second part, you are right, I will edit my answer.

Why $E[X_1^21_{X_1>0}]=\mathbb{P}(X_1>0)E[X_1^2|X_1>0]$? Is $E[X_1^2|X_1>0]$ the same as $E(Z_i^2)$ defined in my question, where $Z_i$ follows the (positive) truncated normal distribution? If $E[X_1^2|X_1>0]$ and $E(Z_i^2)$ are identical, I think your very first equation should be $nE[X_1^21_{X_1>0}]=n\mathbb{P}(X_1>0)E(Z_i^2)$?

Once again, you are right, sorry I missed the error in my previous edit.
